# Tripleloss from Tensorflow add on give reshape error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have been getting this error and cannot figure it out.

```
 ValueError: Cannot reshape a tensor with 48032 elements to shape [32,1] (32 elements) for 'Reshape' (op: 'Reshape') with input shapes: [32,1501], [2] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [32,1].
```

What I am doing is trying to use a tripleloss function from the tensorflow_addons library using an example from here

https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/tutorials/losses_triplet

I pretty much copied it and change the data. 
My data set contains 1501 different classes separated into folders for each class. I am using a data generator from tf.data.Dataset which seems to work fine too.

This is what I have

```
BATCH_SIZE = 32
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,
    shear_range=0,
    rotation_range=20,
    zoom_range=0.15,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest')


ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator=train_datagen.flow_from_directory,
                                    args=[train_dir, (224, 224), 'categorical'],
                                    output_types=(tf.float32, tf.float32),
                                    output_shapes=([32, 224,224,3], [32,1501]))


model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(224, 224, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=None),  # No activation on final dense layer
    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.l2_normalize(x, axis=1))  # L2 normalize embeddings
])
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
              loss=tfa.losses.TripletSemiHardLoss())
history = model.fit(ds, epochs=45, verbose=1, callbacks=None)
```

Its pretty much a verbatim copy other than the dataset.

Do I have to make a map function like ds.map(function)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

exactly the problem I ran into.
As it is stated in https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/losses/TripletSemiHardLoss
"We expect labels y_true to be provided as 1-D integer Tensor with shape [batch_size] of multi-class integer labels."

ImageDataGenerator produces [batchsize,nclasses] tensor which has to be preprocessed to be fed into TripletSemiHardLoss.

I personally just made own trainig function instead of model.fit:

```
for e in range(EPOCHS):
    print('Epoch', e)
    for b in range(int(STEPS_PER_EPOCH)):
        batch=train_data_gen.next()
        x_batch=batch[0]
        y_batch=np.argmax(batch[1],axis=1)  # <- class labels: y_true: 1-D integer 
        history=model.fit(x_batch, y_batch) # 1 step fit
        print(e,b)
```

which does train the model, however at the moment I'm strugling with the loss value, which is random between 0 and 1 at every step. Must be the gradients being lost. Looking into it.

**Edit1**:

actually, this thing works:

```
image_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_data_gen = image_generator.flow_from_directory(directory=str(data_dir),
                                                     batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                                     shuffle=True,
                                                     target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                     classes = list(CLASS_NAMES),
                                                     color_mode='grayscale',
                                                     class_mode='sparse')
model.fit(train_data_gen, epochs=10)
```

The magic was to use class_mode='sparse'

Comment: Good stuff mate.